# Какая самая простая и популярная архитектура приложения на 2 экрана?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Если необходимо создать Приложение на 2 экрана, чтобы из одной вьюхи был переход по кнопке в другую вьюху - для этого нужно 2 разных вьюконтроллера? И можно ли обойтись без NavigationViewController?

Как выглядит стандартная архитектура такого приложения?

Comment: Для wpf используйте Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для такого маленького приложения можно воспользоваться архитектурой MVC от Apple (модификация MVC для iOS-приложений). Информации об архитектуре и особенностях её применения полно даже в материалах на Apple Developer. [image: картинка архитектуры Apple MVC]

Для нативной, красивой и функциональной реализации перехода между двумя экранами с максимальной простотой следует воспользоваться UINavigationViewController и оформить экраны как разные UIViewController'ы. Отказываться от NavigationController'а нет никакого смысла в вашем случае.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Это именно то, что мне нужно было.

Comment: Если ответ вас устроил, примите его (галочка возле ответа)

Comment: Готово! Спасибо еще раз